# Solace : Topic Endpoint Subscription is not working for me

Tags: solace

I am new to solace world, Can someone please same any example of subscription to durable topic endpoint in solace API.

Comment: Would be helpful if you describe what type language you needed as an example?

Answer (score 1):

A topic endpoint in Solace is a guaranteed messaging object that acts as a holding area for messages for a consumer. It attracts messages published to a topic for which the topic endpoint has a matching topic subscription. The topic subscription for the topic endpoint is specified in the client request to bind a flow to that topic endpoint. Topic Endpoints are equivalent to durable topic subscriptions in JMS.

You can read more about how to create and configure a topic endpoint [here](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Configuring-DTEs.htm)

Durability in Solace refers to the lifetime of and endpoint created. You can read more about Endpoint Durability [here](https://docs.solace.com/Features/Endpoints.htm?Highlight=exclusive#Endpoint_Durability)